# Change rigidbodys default height from floor?

Tags: unity, physics

I am new to unity and I have a few questions:

There is a mesh that has a rigidbody and a box collider that I placed on the scene.
I also added a generic terrain to the scene from the 3D objects menu.
When I put the mesh at a certain height and it drops I notice that it always stops at **Y = 0.500000**.
How do I change this default value? What controls this? For example, does unity have it so that when any other type of collider hits the **terraincollider** the **other collider** automatically updates the rigidbody to be 0.50000 above it and this only happens when it hits a terrain collider?

If this is the case, Is this **causing a collision every frame** and **adjusting it to 0.50000 every frame** so it doesnt fall through?

Finally, assuming that the **Y = 0.50000** value above the ground cannot be changed, if I wanted something to "hoover" above the ground, would I always need to take that the maximum amount that I can get to the ground is **Y = 0.500000**?

Comment: Is your collider larger than your displayed mesh? Show us what you see in the Scene View when you have your object's box collider expanded in the Inspector.

Comment: @DMGregory Its just a cube, I havent changed anything in the collider, I basically just added a rigid body to the cube, basically if you make a new terrain and cube then add a rigid body to the cube thats exactly what I have. It keeps stopping at Y = 0.50000, but I want to know why, and if it can be changed, as the question says.

Comment: A unit cube, that's 1 unit wide, meaning the bottom surface that hits the ground is 0.5 units below the pivot at the center that lists your coordinates? I feel like that may be a clue. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I change this default value? What controls this?

As DMGregory was hinting, a 1 meter box has a center at 0.5m. So if the bottom of the box is touching the ground, the center of the box will be 0.5 meters above the ground.

> Is this causing a collision every frame and adjusting it to 0.50000 every frame so it doesnt fall through?

No, when a Rigidbody comes to a resting position it starts "sleeping", meaning that the physics engine recognizes that it's at rest and stops processing its physics until something moves it. See [the Rigidbody documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/RigidbodiesOverview.html):

> When a Rigidbody is moving slower than a defined minimum linear or rotational speed, the physics engine assumes it has come to a halt. When this happens, the GameObject does not move again until it receives a collision or force, and so it is set to “sleeping” mode. This optimisation means that no processor time is spent updating the Rigidbody until the next time it is “awoken” (that is, set in motion again).

Although the [description from Unity's ancient history](https://docs.unity3d.com/430/Documentation/Components/RigidbodySleeping.html) may be easier to digest at first glance:

> When Rigidbodies fall to rest - a box landing on the floor - they will start sleeping. Sleeping is an optimization which allows the Physics Engine to stop processing those rigidbodies.

Comment: Thank you. So how does unity determine that? Does it calculate the center of every mesh, then determines the distance from the center to the edge of the mesh using the Y positioning of global,  For example: For a cube that is (1,1,1), Y = 1, so the distance from the center to the edge of the mesh in the global Y direction is 0.5, now place the center of the mesh 0.5 units from the ground and draw the mesh around it?

Comment: @user145001 You can change the Center of the collider in the settings of each Collider component attached to a game object. Default is 0:0:0 which is the geometric center of the collider. And no, it's not global Y. It takes the rotation of the collider into account. So when a box collider is standing on its edge, then the center will be 0.72 units above ground.